# multiplying columns in a df using python

Tags: multiple-columns, multiplication

I have a df as follows

```
       USD      Weight %
```

0     850,910,498,731                      2.325581
1     850,910,498,731                      9.325581
2     850,910,498,731                      2.325532
3     850,910,498,731                      4.325343
4     850,910,498,731                      8.325581
5     850,910,498,731                      2.325581
6     850,910,498,731                      9.325581

I want to create another column called dollars which will multiply USD and weight % columns together. I am using the below code to do it but i keep getting an error.

```
df['$'] = df['USD'] * df['Weight %']
```

the error i keep getting is

ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('

Comment: the full error is = ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')

Comment: Please tag your question with the relevant language and environment

Comment: just changed it, does that help? sorry i'm new to python and still learning the ropes

Comment: what's the output of `df.dtypes`?

Comment: df['USD'] = object
and df['Weight %'] = float